# 3D LIDAR SLAM in 2020

Tags: slam, navigation, ros-melodic, 3d-slam, 3dslam

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi,

I have been using RTABMAP for SLAM with a stereo_camera, and it is working very well.  It seems well maitained by the activity on the github page.

Now I am looking to perform the same task with a 3D LIDAR, but I cannot find a package that seems to be maintained.
I checked: BLAM (last update 2016) and SegMatch (last update 2017).

Does anyone has a suggestion of a package that I can use?
I am using ROS Melodic , but I am willing to migrate to Noetic.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/352162/3d-lidar-slam-in-2020/) by [czr](https://answers.ros.org/users/54143/czr/) on ROS Answers with karma: 5 on 2020-05-12

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Rtabmap can use 3D Lidar pretty ok. Cartographer, LegoLoam or hdl_graph_slam are maybe other options for you as they are a bit more up to date.

```
<node pkg="rtabmap_ros" type="rtabmap" name="rtabmap" output="screen" args="-d">
  <param name="subscribe_rgbd"       type="bool" value="false"/>
  <param name="frame_id"             type="string" value="$(arg frame_id)"/>
  <param name="subscribe_depth"      type="bool" value="false"/>
  <param name="subscribe_rgb"        type="bool" value="false"/>
  <param name="subscribe_scan_cloud" type="bool" value="true"/>
  <param name="approx_sync"          type="bool" value="true"/>
  
  <remap from="scan_cloud" to="/os1_cloud_node/points"/>
  <remap from="grid_map" to="/map"/>

  <!-- RTAB-Map's parameters -->
  <param name="Rtabmap/DetectionRate"          type="string" value="1"/>
  <param name="RGBD/NeighborLinkRefining"      type="string" value="false"/>
  <param name="RGBD/ProximityMaxGraphDepth"    type="string" value="0"/>
  <param name="RGBD/ProximityPathMaxNeighbors" type="string" value="1"/>
  <param name="RGBD/AngularUpdate"             type="string" value="0.05"/>
  <param name="Mem/NotLinkedNodesKept"         type="string" value="false"/>
  <param name="Mem/STMSize"                    type="string" value="30"/>

  <param name="Reg/Strategy"                   type="string" value="1"/>
  <param name="Grid/CellSize"                  type="string" value="0.2"/>
  <param name="Grid/RangeMax"                  type="string" value="20"/>
  <param name="Grid/ClusterRadius"             type="string" value="1"/>
  <param name="Grid/GroundIsObstacle"          type="string" value="false"/>
  <param name="Grid/RayTracing"                type="string" value="true"/>
  <param name="Grid/3D"                        type="string" value="false"/>
  <param name="Grid/MaxObstacleHeight"         type="string" value="1.5"/>

</node>
```

---

Originally posted by [bob-ROS](https://answers.ros.org/users/45543/bob-ros/) with karma: 525 on 2020-05-12

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 4

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [stevemacenski](https://answers.ros.org/users/25940/stevemacenski/) on 2020-05-12**:
I've heard recommendations for HDL.

**Comment by [czr](https://answers.ros.org/users/54143/czr/) on 2020-05-12**:
Thank you. Can I use a LIDAR standalone on Rtabmap? I though that I needed a stereo camera or a depth camera in parallel.

**Comment by [bob-ROS](https://answers.ros.org/users/45543/bob-ros/) on 2020-05-13**:
I updated my answer with the config I used for a OS1-16 channel LiDAR.

**Comment by [czr](https://answers.ros.org/users/54143/czr/) on 2020-05-25**:
Thanks for your answer, I created a launch file based on your example, but I cannot get the /cloud_map and /cloud_ground topics. They get published but /cloud_ground yields an empty cloud while /cloud_map seems to have data, but nothing shows up in Rviz. I used the same RTAB-Map's parameters that I used for my stereo camera setup.

**Comment by [bob-ROS](https://answers.ros.org/users/45543/bob-ros/) on 2020-05-25**:
Hm, I dunno. Should probably ask a new question, I've never used the ground from rtabmap, only the 2D grid_map.